# Get an array of unique values out from filtered data in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, unique

[image]

As shown in the image, I want to first filter by column A for "Yes".

[image]

The above image shows after the filter and I want to save each **unique** "ID" in columns B and put them into an array called `myArr`. Ideally, `myArr = [101, 5137, 97]` and I would be able to call each value in the array using `myArr(1), myArr(2), myArr(3)`

Below is the code I had, but there are 2 problems:

1. my `arr` doesn't seem to be an actual array
2. it doesn't print the correct answers `101, 5137, 97`. Instead, it only prints out `101, 5137`

```vb
    With [a1].CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 1, "Yes"
        'first create arr which include duplicated data
        arr = .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
        'myArr is an array with unique values
        myArr = Application.Unique(arr)
        'print out each value of myArr to check if myArr is correct
        For Each num In myArr
            Debug.Print num
        Next num
        .AutoFilter
    End With
```

Please give me some ideas on what's wrong with my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because once you apply the filter, the range is no longer contiguous.  Your method will only capture a contiguous range.

Because you are setting the Autofilter value from within your routine, lets just check the values inside of an array, and then add the correct values to a dictionary, which will only accept unique values anyways.

```
Public Sub testUniqueArray()

    Dim arrTemp As Variant, key As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long

    arrTemp = [a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
        If arrTemp(i, 1) = "Yes" Then
            dict(arrTemp(i, 2)) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key
    Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does this line do `dict(arrTemp(i, 2)) = 1`?

Comment: It's a quick way to add a key to the Dictionary without worrying about duplicates.  It is actually assigning a value to the dictionary key.  When assigning a value, if the key does not exist it will be created. If the key exists the value will be changed.  If you were to use the `dict.Add Key:="5137"` method, you would trigger an error if there was already a 5137 key. @JackeyOL

Comment: That's a very clever way, but why do we need to use a dictionary here as we are actually only using the keys but not its values at all. Is that an Excel VBA thing? I'm wondering if there is a simple list that we can use in VBA as we do in other languages?

Comment: You don't have to use a dictionary.  You could use an array, a collection or a dictionary.  In this instance, with you only wanting to keep unique values, I think a dictionary is they easiest way to do so.  You may find this post about [collections and dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479842/comparison-of-dictionary-collections-and-arrays) interesting or useful. @JackeyOL

Answer (score 1):

### Unique Values from Filtered Column to Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintUniqueValues()
    
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 1
    Const ValueColumn As Long = 2
    Const CriteriaString As String = "Yes"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' You better improve e.g. by using the worksheet (tab) name...
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' ... or by using the code name:
    'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, CriteriaString
    
    Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = ArrUniqueFromFilteredColumn(rg, ValueColumn)
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If IsEmpty(Arr) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Either (preferred when dealing with arrays)...
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(n)
    Next n

    ' ... or:
'    Dim Item As Variant
'    For Each Item In Arr
'        Debug.Print Item
'    Next Item

End Sub

Function ArrUniqueFromFilteredColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal ValueColumn As Long) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ValueColumn < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ValueColumn > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = rg.Columns(ValueColumn).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim CellsCount As Long
    CellsCount = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, crg) ' 103 - CountA
    If CellsCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' no match or only empty cells
    'Debug.Print "CellsCount = " & CellsCount
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = crg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each cCell In scrg.Cells
        Key = cCell.Value
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                dict(Key) = Empty
                ' The previous line is a short version of:
                'If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then dict.Add Key, Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next cCell
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only errors and blanks
    'Debug.Print "dict.Count = " & dict.Count
    
    ArrUniqueFromFilteredColumn = dict.Keys
    
End Function
```